# Trying to display data from a module's table in views

Tags: views

I'm trying to show the purl.value value on a view's page.

It seems to be grabbing all of the data, however it isn't showing in the final results. Here's my code:

```
function mymodule_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  //watchdog("view information", print_r($view, true));
  if ($view->name == 'project_management') {



    $join = new views_join;
  $join->table ='purl';
  $join->left_table = 'node';
  $join->left_field = 'nid';
  $join->field = 'id';
  $join->type = "LEFT";
  $join->extra_type = 'AND';
  $join->adjusted = 'TRUE';


    $view->query->table_queue['purl'] = array(
    'table' => 'purl',
    'num' => 1,
    'alias' => 'purl',
    'join' => $join,
    'relationship' => 'node',
  );

    $view->query->tables['purl'] = array(
    'count' => 1,
    'alias' => 'purl'
  );

$view->query->add_field('purl', 'value');
  }
}
```

What exactly am I missing? Do I need a view handler? I was told that maybe using hook_views_data_alter() might be better for my purposes.

How do I add a visible custom piece of data from that column on my view page?

Answer (score 1):

you should map your data to views, so it will be available from views admin UI

check [This tutorial](http://evolvingweb.ca/story/developing-views-part-i-describing-your-data-views) where you will find the basics for describe custom data and tables to views.